# Make a button click change a picture in the picture box visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I have one picture box and multiple buttons on Visual Basic 2010 Express. I'm looking for an example code for putting a picture in the box when I click the button and it changing when I click another button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you use VBA like you tagged your question (before edit)... then try this.

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
    picture1.Picture = "C:\1.jpg"
End Sub

Private Sub button2_Click()
 picture1.Picture = "C:\2.jpg"
End Sub
```

if its vb.net (which i indicate because you said visual studio 2010 express) try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\2.jpg")
End Sub
```

exception handling is up to you :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Its vb.net I'm in computer science one in my high school I'm in 11th grade and computers have fascinated me since when I got a phoenix computer with windows 95.